# Wifi Vendor changed after reinstall

Tags: wireless, intel, realtek, iwlwifi, dkms

I recently reinstalled Ubuntu 17.10 on my machine. On the first install, my wifi card was detected as having a realtek chipset and was using the r8168-dkms driver without issues. After the reinstall, the wifi card is shown as having an Intel Wireless chipset and is now using iwlwifi. Anyone have any idea what's happened here?

The card in question is a Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I. From what I can see online, gigabyte uses both realtek and intel chips in different releases of these cards.

Comment: The r8168-dkms is for ethernet

Comment: Good to know. Any idea why Ubuntu sees the card as having a different vendor than before?